# How to debug issue on different browser with different versions at same time

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, testing, google-chrome

Currently i am testing Web UI Interface and have to test it on different browser and their different version. Is there any way i have one browser open with multiple tabs on it with different versions and the testing i do on one tab reflects on all and if there is any issues it will highlights accordingly. Applies to iexplorer, firefox, chrome etc.

Its because i faced one issue specific to Firefox 3.6.27 and that issue does not exists on FF 9 , 10 , 11.

NOTE: i have found tool IETester – Multiple Internet Explorer versions on the same PC which is useful in case for Internet Explorer. Need some thing similar for Firefox as well as Chrome.

Comment: As per my knowledge,  you cant have the different versions of browser on different tabs.  For that you need different versions of that browser which you can do it by using virtual OS.

Comment: Abby i have IETester Tool installed on my system and it can open different versions of  IE explorer. Just wondering to see if i can get it for Firefox or Chrome. BTW i have been following the same approach of having different VM's configured for different  browers (with different version).

Answer (score 0):

Try [spoon.net.](http://spoon.net/)
It allows you to run multiple versions of browsers at the same time such as IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc,.  It's not very expensive.